# Argumentos por medio de CMD - Java

Tags: java, poo, cmd

Necesito crear un convertidor de grados, de centígrados a fahrenheit y viceversa. El programa deberá **recibir dos parámetros al ejecutarse**. Uno el **identificador de la conversión** (centígrados o fahrenheit) y en segundo lugar **la cantidad a convertir**.

Ejemplo si deseas convertir 30 grados centígrados a fahrenheit  se deberá ejecutar el programa de la siguiente manera:

`# java centigrados 30`

Como respuesta el software debe regresar

`# 86 grados fahrenheit`

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes iTzprodigui, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que comprendas el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtendrás tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Por favor revisa [ask], que haz intentado?

Comment: ¿Y cual es tu duda/problema?

Comment: Te sugiero que leas [Java Command-line arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html). Es la documentación oficial Oracle. Está en inglés, puedes traducirla con el servicio de Chrome. Luego, intenta realizar el ejercico tu mismo, es decir, embárrate las manos. Y si tienes algún problema, vuelves por aqui y lo planteas, con gusto te ayudamos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que declarar la variable f y c dentro de tu función, por ejemplo:

```
float cefa(float valor){
    float f = (valor*1.8)+32;
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Me sirvio, le asigne el valor float, pero me indicaba esto:
```CGF.java:40: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float
                return f;```
y lo cambie por un double tanto el float del cefa y face y ahora solo me indica que:
```CGF.java:37: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
1 error```

Comment: Es por el float, le tienes que hacer un cast al resultado
float f = (float)((valor*1.8)+32);
sin embargo te recomiendo que uses double

Answer (score 0):

Que tal chicos he logrado un avance con este trabajo pero ahora tengo un obstáculo y no se que podría ser :S Me podrían orientar para corregirlo?

```
    public class CGF {

    // public CGF(){
    //  f = 0;
    //  c = 0;
    // }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String identificador = args[0];
        String cantidad = String.valueOf(args[1]);
        float f;
        float c;

    }

     float Conversor(float valor, String identificador){
        if (identificador.equals("centigrados")) {
            System.out.println(cefa(valor) + "grados fahrenheit");
        }else if (identificador.equals("fahrenheit")) {
            System.out.println(face(valor) + "grados centigrados");
        }
    }
    float cefa(float valor){
        f = (valor*1.8)+32;
        return f;
    }
    float face(float valor){
        c =(valor-32)/1.8;
        return c;
    }
}
```

cuando intento compilar la consola me lanza:

```
C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop>javac CGF.java
CGF.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                f = (valor*1.8)+32;
                ^
  symbol:   variable f
  location: class CGF
CGF.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
                return f;
                       ^
  symbol:   variable f
  location: class CGF
CGF.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
                c =(valor-32)/1.8;
                ^
  symbol:   variable c
  location: class CGF
CGF.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
                return c;
                       ^
  symbol:   variable c
  location: class CGF
4 errors
```

Comment: Hola, este espacio es para respuestas. Si tu pregunta original ya tuvo una respuesta satisfactoria deberías darla como válida, así tu reputación y la de quien respondió sube. Si tienes otra pregunta (como la que pusiste aquí en el espacio de respuestas), debes formularla como una pregunta nueva. Es mi recomendación. Ya que si la publicas aquí, aparte que no es correcto, nadie la verá como una pregunta y por ende no recibirá respuestas. Saludos